# jquery in editorfor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to use jquery in asp.net mvc3. I'm using EditorTemplates for the list. My model is as

```
public class staffinfo
{
    public int staffid { get; set; }
    public double extgrade { get; set; }
    public string lvlid { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> level { get; set; }
    public string grdid { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> grade { get; set; }
    public double pf { get; set; }       
    public double wages { get; set; }
    public List<hrfacility> facility { get; set; }

}

public class hrfacility
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }        
    public int staffid { get; set; }
    public string staffname { get; set; }               
    public double amount { get; set; }
    public bool selected { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
...
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.wages)    
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.facility)
```

EditorTemplate for hrfacility

```
@model Mysol.Models.hrfacility
...
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.name)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.selected)    
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.staffname)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.amount)

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#staffname').attr('readonly', true);
</script>
```

I've used the above procedure without the list part in editortemplates and the jquery works fine but for this particular situation it is not working!!

Is it because there might be more than one staffname??

How can i make jquery work for the above situation (make staffname readonly)??

P.S. readonly is just for the example purpose. I need to do other things as well with jquery like assigning the value to the textbox. If i can get this work, i think i can do other things as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because the id of the input for `staffname` should be something like `facility_0_staffname` , `facility_1_staffname` and so on.

You better add a class to the `staffname` input and access it with that class.

You may check the id with Firebug (on Firefox)

Comment: Can we use loop in jquery to use the needed textboxes?? If so how??

Comment: @BJ.BJ: Of course, use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/). However, you do not need this to do this task. Just do- `$(".classname").attr('readonly', true)` and it will be done.

Answer (score 1):

Bj,

I think your best bet might be to work on a `class`, rather than an `Id`, given that you have multiples. You could try:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.staffname, new { @class = "staffname" })

....    

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.staffname').attr('readonly', true);
    });
</script>
```

(notice you can't use `EditorFor` as this wont accept `htmlAttributes`, you must use the base inputtype, but that wont matter as you 'know' you want to display it in a readonly textbox)

**[Edit]** - of course, if using the textbox, there's no need at all to use a class, you can of course just add the style 'inline' to achieve the same result:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.staffname, new { @readonly = "true" })
```

OR (browser quirks):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.staffname, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

**N.B**

one further thing to add, there's a remote chance (depending on your javascript loading) that the EditorFor template is actually being called BEFORE the jquery library is being loaded. Check that this is not the case by looking at the generated source. Prolly not an issue but one that has caught me out before with editorfor templates and partials.

Comment: I've already tried this and it doesn't work either :( Maybe it's because of the use of list. Otherwise there was no problem at all. But I need list for this purpose. Is there any other way? Maybe not using editor templates??

Comment: well, if you use the @Html.TextBoxFor, you could add the readonly attr directly onto the helper, rather than using javascript. see edit above

Comment: you need to remove the javascript stuff to do with staffname in case that's interfering. the attr update `new { @readonly = "true" }` or `new { @readonly = "readonly" }` should universally work on ANY input type. weird

Comment: readonly attribute is working. Thanks. Can we assign classes dynamically? Like if there are two textbox, the classes will be text1,text2 and likewise for the number of textboxes??

Comment: bj -feel free to add a little upvote/mark as answer if this helped  :-). seriously tho, if you use classes, then it's imaterial what the input elements are called, just apply the class to the element and let your js code do the heavy lifting for you

Comment: Thanks jim, my textboxes are now readonly. But as i've already stated in my question i need the jquery to fire for my purpose. Readonly was just used for the example purpose though it is one of the things i need (see my P.S. section).